# Pyplot plot function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Given below is the code for plotting points using pyplot.

```
x1=300+p[k]*math.cos(val[thetaval])
y1=300+p[k]*math.sin(val[thetaval])
plt.plot(x1,y1,'k.')
```

The plotting is working fine, the problem is, if I want to plot it as a point I am specifying the dot in `'k.'` inside the plot function. The output is something like:

[image]

The width of the black line/curve that I am plotting is much more that needed. How to reduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are not plotting a line but a series of small points. Maybe if you try setting the `markersize` argument of the `plot` function could work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [documentation of plot()](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot) you can find "linewidth"

So use:

```
plt.plot(x1,y1,'k.', linewidth=0.1)
```

Comment: I tried that already. The width is not decreasing. I also tried `lw`, still no change.

Comment: so what about using linewidth... they got an example: `plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3], 'go-', label='line 1', linewidth=2)` linewidth or lw = float value in points

Comment: Tried linewidth, no change. I referred the documentation. Is there anyway it is not working because I am plotting points and not a line?

Comment: Yes, try it. Also the linewidth = 0.5 , 1 , 0.01. Couldn't find the the interval for that and I cant test for you from this PC :)